# Very difficult sequence

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I show this? I tried with the definiton of the exponential function but it didn't work.

$$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{(4n^7+3^n)^n}{3^{n^2}+(-9)^n\log(n)}=1$$

I hope somebody could help.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference

Comment: Do you mean $ \lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{ (4n^7 + 3^n)^n}{ 3^{n^2} + (-9)^n\log n} = 1 $ or $ \lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{ (4n^7 + 3^n)^n}{ 3^{n^2} + (-9)^{n\log n}} = 1 $

Comment: it should be ((-9)^n )* log(n)

Comment: @calculus certainly the former, for the sake of being defined

Comment: yes i mean the left one :)

Comment: @Noob3D O.K. It wasn´t sure.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\frac{ (4n^7 + 3^n)^n}{  3^{n^2} + (-9)^n\log n}=
\frac{3^{n^2}\left(4\frac{n^7}{3^n}+1\right)^n}{3^{n^3}\left(1+(-9)^n\frac{\log n}{3^{n^2}}\right)}
$$
The brackets in the denominator go to $1$. Next
$$
\left(4\frac{n^7}{3^n}+1\right)^n=
\left[\left(\frac1{3^n/{4n^7}}+1\right)^{{3^n/4n^7}}\right]^{\frac{4n^8}{3^n}}
$$
which tends to $e^0=1$. Thus your limit goes to $1$.

Comment: I managed to simplify it till there, but how should I go on?

Comment: I think that in your last expression you have the first exponent backwards: you want an expression of the form $\;\left(1+\frac1{a_n}\right)^{a_n}\;$ , with $\;\lim a_n=\infty$

Comment: Yeah I got confused, thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Additional hint:
For $0<\let\epsilon\varepsilon\epsilon<1$,
$$1<(1+\epsilon)^n<\frac1{(1-\epsilon)^n }$$
and by Bernoullli
$$ (1-\epsilon)^n\ge 1-n\epsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

For term $(4n^{7}+3^{n})^{n}$ since $n‎\longrightarrow‎ \infty$ is equal to $3^{n^{2}}$. The denominator is the same and result is routine.

Comment: how can you see this?

Comment: The limit of an expression depending on $\;n\;$ can **not** be again an expression in $\;n\;$ ... This is wrong.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation